# How can I concatenate strings in SQLDF in R

Tags: r, string, sqldf

I am looking for a function to concatenate two strings inside SQLDF in R, that works like paste(), but could not find any. The reason for doing that is I want to concatenate two columns while joining two data frames. Instead of using merge() to do the join then use paste(), I sometimes want to use sqldf().

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use the syntax for concatenation in SQL, e.g.,

```
d <- data.frame(x = c("a", "b"), y = c("1", "2"))
sqldf("select *, x||y from d")

#   x y x||y
# 1 a 1   a1
# 2 b 2   b2
```

Comment: how do you add a separator - so final result would be `a-1` instead of `a1`?

Comment: @nak5120 just add it in: `sqldf("select *, x||'-'||y from d")`