# How to avoid use of concat

Tags: sql

I got a piece of SQL code I need to rewrite to a version that does not use the concat function.

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE concat(name_1, name_2) in (select concat(name_1, name_2) from B)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: @frlan no. Trying to prep a ABT for processing in R but the SQL package in there does not support the concat funtion.

Comment: If concat() is not supported there must be another concatenation operator supported like `||` or `+`. Did you try any of them?

Answer (score 2):

Check that substrings of equal lengths are the same:

## Oracle SQL

(Since you haven't tagged the question with the SQL dialect you are using, however you can adapt the answer to any SQL dialect.)

So, if your sample data is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a ( name_1, name_2 ) AS
SELECT 'ABC', 'DEF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI', 'JKL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MNO', 'PQR' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE b ( name_1, name_2 ) AS
SELECT 'ABC', 'DEF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GH', 'IJKL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- same letters, left-hand side is shorter
SELECT 'MNOP', 'QR' FROM DUAL;          -- same letters, left-hand side is longer
```

Then you can use the query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   A
WHERE  EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM   B
  WHERE  LENGTH( A.name_1 ) + LENGTH( a.name_2 )
          = LENGTH( b.name_1 ) + LENGTH( b.name_2 )
  AND    (  ( A.name_1 = B.name_1 AND A.name_2 = B.name_2 )
         OR (   LENGTH( A.name_1 ) < LENGTH( B.name_1 )
            AND A.name_1 = SUBSTR( b.name_1, 1, LENGTH( a.name_1 ) )
            AND SUBSTR( A.name_2, 1, LENGTH( b.name_1 ) - LENGTH ( a.name_1 ) )
                = SUBSTR( b.name_1, LENGTH( a.name_1 ) + 1 )
            AND SUBSTR( a.name_2, LENGTH( a.name_2 ) - LENGTH( b.name_2 ) + 1 )
                = B.name_2
            )
         OR (   LENGTH( A.name_1 ) > LENGTH( B.name_1 )
            AND b.name_1 = SUBSTR( a.name_1, 1, LENGTH( b.name_1 ) )
            AND SUBSTR( b.name_2, 1, LENGTH( a.name_1 ) - LENGTH ( b.name_1 ) )
                = SUBSTR( a.name_1, LENGTH( b.name_1 ) + 1 )
            AND SUBSTR( b.name_2, LENGTH( b.name_2 ) - LENGTH( a.name_2 ) + 1 )
                = a.name_2
            )
         )
)
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> NAME_1 | NAME_2
> :----- | :-----
> ABC    | DEF   
> GHI    | JKL   
> MNO    | PQR
> ```

The same output as for your query using `CONCAT`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=73d71719002fdf528b4d5b7f97339956)*

---

Or you may be able to use [the `||` concatenation operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27995009/how-can-i-concatenate-strings-in-sqldf-in-r):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE name_1 || name_2 in (select name_1 || name_2 from B)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cea54d70f32b156903f9a0b2754e6d81)*